# Extract same elements from two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given two lists

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,4,6,7]
```

output similar element

```
c = [2,4]
```

Is there API to compare and extract similar elements from two lists? It could be possible to do it by compare element by element, but I am wondering if there are already API.

Comment: Another option would be to make some effort and search for the numerous solutions that would be available.

Comment: @devnull: Then at least call it `set` (lowercase) for the built-in type.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My bad!  Now this does deserve a few answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
print set(a).intersection(set(b))
```

use intersection to get common elements in the both list